# Why would I even use istream::ignore when checking for valid input?

Tags: c++, windows, istream

The [C++ FAQ over at parashift](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.3) uses something similar to the following:

```
while (cout << "Enter an integer: " && !(cin >> foo))
{
    cin.clear();

    //feel free to replace this with just (80, '\n') for my point
    cin.ignore (numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

The `cin.ignore (...)`, however, seems unnecessary. Why can't I just use `cin.sync()`? It's shorter and does not require a length. It's also more versatile as it will work the same way whether or not there are any characters in the input buffer in the first place. I've tested this once in the same loop as I used with `ignore` and it worked the same way. Yet it seems every example involving this type of input validation uses `ignore` instead of `sync`.

What (if any) was the reasoning behind using `ignore` when there's a much simpler alternative?

If it matters:
Windows
GCC
MinGW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On an ifstream, the effect of `sync()` is implementation defined (per C++11, §27.9.1.5/19) -- there's no guarantee that it'll do what you want (and no real guarantee of what it'll do at all). In a typical case, it will be about equivalent to the `ignore` if and only if the stream is line buffered -- but if the stream is unbuffered, it probably won't do anything, and if the stream is fully buffered, it'll probably do bad things.

Comment: Always with the implementation-defined, huh. I guess it would be a good candidate for that purpose if it wasn't.

Comment: @chris: yes, if it would dependably do what you want, it would be a good candidate to do what you want. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Both do different things. `sync` discards characters already read ahead, no matter how many there are, or what they are. On the other hand, `ignore` discards characters until a certain character is encountered, no matter whether those characters have already been read, or whether there are more characters already read ahead. For example, imagine that `cin` has a 40 byte buffer, but your line had 80 bytes. Then most likely the first 40 bytes had been read to `cin`'s buffer. After you've interpreted the beginning of those, by calling `sync` you discard the rest of *those 40 characters you already have read*, but *not* the other 40 characters in the line. On the other hand, your input might come from a pipe where no line buffering is typically done. In that case, you may discard not only the current line, but also parts of the next line which have been read ahead. OTOH with `ignore` you always know for sure that you'll always read up to the next `\n` (assuming the maximal number of characters to ignore is high enough to encounter it).